# extracting data from tow different files to produce a fasta file

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have two different files one is a fasta file, and the other a txt file produced from a dictionary with json.

file_A looks like this;

```
 > {
      "gene_1005 ['gene description_B']":2,
      "gene_1009 ['gene description_C']":1,
      "gene_104 ['gene description_D']":2,
      "gene_1046 ['gene description_A']":1,

}
```

file_B looks like this:

> gene_1005 ['gen description_B'] ATGTGGATCCGCCCGTTGCAGGCGGAACTGAGCGATAACACGCTGGCTTTGTATGCGCCAAACCGTTTTGTGCTCGA
>    gene_2 ['gene description_C'] ATGAAATTTACCGTTGAACGTGAACATTTATTAAAACCGCTGCAACAGGTGAGTGGCCCATTAGGTGGCCGCCCAAC

what I would like to create is a new fasta file only containing those genes that have the value 2 in the file_A. I have tried the code below but I am quite lost. It will print the word[0], that is the name of the gene but it will not print word[1], that should be the number. It sends the error

> 'out of range'

```
import json

def readlines():
    input_file=open('file_A.txt')
    lines=input_file.readlines()
    print lines[1]
    for line in lines:

        words=lines.split(':')

        print words[0]
        print words[1]


    #print line
input_file.close()
```

readlines()

Could anyone kindly give a hand with this, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see people like giving negative without explaining why or giving an suggestion, and that was the suggestion of this post. But as I see that the negative-voter has not bother with a suggestion, I will post the answer to it.

```
input_file= open('file.fa', 'r')
output_file= open(wanted_genes.fa', 'w')
for line in input_file:
if line[0]=='>':
   geneID=line[1:-1]

  if geneID in my_dict:
    output_file.write(line)
    skip=0
  else:
    skip=1
else:
    if not skip:
    output_file.write(line)
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```